# what happens to protected members after inheritance in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

As in C++ protected members were becoming private in private inheritance .
so I am very confused what happens in Java . do here access specifiers remain same or what? like

if suppose below code exists then now shiva will still remain protected  inside classB ? can we again use it in classC ?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
package package1
class classA
{
protected shiva;
}

////////////////////////
import package1
package package2
class classB extends classA
{}

//////////////////////
import package2
class classC extends classB
{}
```

Comment: In java, the inheritance is similar to the C++ public virtual inheritance. So, all access modifiers will remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the protected field in the subclass.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You can use it.

```
            │ Class │ Package │ Subclass │ Subclass │ World
            │       │         │(same pkg)│(diff pkg)│ 
────────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────
public      │   +   │    +    │    +     │     +    │   +     
────────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────
protected   │   +   │    +    │    +     │     +    │         
────────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────
no modifier │   +   │    +    │    +     │          │    
────────────┼───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────
private     │   +   │         │          │          │    

 + : accessible         blank : not accessible
```

For more reference, please find the answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in). It seems to me similar.

Answer (score 1):

Protected access modifier lies between the public and default access modifier. It can be accessed outside the package but only through subclasses.

Refer this link for more clarity.

https://www.tutorialride.com/core-java/inheritance-access-modifiers-in-java.htm

So yes you can use it in the subclasses.